# Iterating through lists with different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, oop

I'm trying to iterate through 4 columns in a CSV that each contain a different amount sale ids.
I make a pandas dataframe and convert each row to a list.
If a column has a greater amount of sale ids than the following column it gives me an error:

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/form[1]/div/select/option[@value=nan]"}

however if all columns have the same amount of id's each, the code works fine.

```
    def get_report_data(self):
        current_date = helpers.currentDate
        data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rford\Desktop\sale_ids.csv')
        everyone_ids = data['Everyone'].tolist()
        dd_ids = data['Daily Deal'].tolist()
        targeted_ids = data['Targeted'].tolist()
        push_ids = data['Push Notification'].tolist()
        acq_ids = data['Acquisition'].tolist()
        for form_code, sales_type, idlist in (
        ( 1, "Everyone", everyone_ids ),
        ( 1, "Daily Deal", dd_ids ),
        ( 2, "Targeted", targeted_ids ),
        ( 2, "Push Notification", push_ids ),
        ( 2, "Acquisition", acq_ids ) ):
            print('Gathering {} Sale Information'.format(sales_type))
            for sale_id in idlist:
                results = []
                helpers.WebDriverWait(helpers.driver, 10)
                helpers.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form[{}]/div/select/option[@value={}]'.format(form_code, sale_id)).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in function `any` might be useful in conjunction with each list's `pop` method:

```
def get_report_data(self):
    current_date = helpers.currentDate
    data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rford\Desktop\sale_ids.csv')
    everyone_ids = data['Everyone'].tolist()
    dd_ids = data['Daily Deal'].tolist()
    targeted_ids = data['Targeted'].tolist()
    push_ids = data['Push Notification'].tolist()
    acq_ids = data['Acquisition'].tolist()
    for form_code, sales_type, idlist in (
    ( 1, "Everyone", everyone_ids ),
    ( 1, "Daily Deal", dd_ids ),
    ( 2, "Targeted", targeted_ids ),
    ( 2, "Push Notification", push_ids ),
    ( 2, "Acquisition", acq_ids ) ):
        print('Gathering {} Sale Information'.format(sales_type))
        while any(idlist):
            results = []
            helpers.WebDriverWait(helpers.driver, 10)
            helpers.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                '/html/body/form[{}]/div/select/option[@value={}]'.format(
                    form_code, idlist.pop(0)
                )
            ).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out pandas was reading some cells of the csv as float.
The fix ended up being to use .fillna(0) on my dataframe and then turn each column to a list and make them integers with .astype(int)

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rford\Desktop\sale_ids.csv')
        data = df.fillna(0)
        everyone_ids = data['Everyone'].astype(int).tolist()
        dd_ids = data['Daily Deal'].astype(int).tolist()
        targeted_ids = data['Targeted'].astype(int).tolist()
        push_ids = data['Push Notification'].astype(int).tolist()
        acq_ids = data['Acquisition'].astype(int).tolist()
```